# Is there any way to filter the workspace references (Ctrl+Shift+G) in eclipse so as NOT to also see the "potential matches"?

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

In eclipse, i want to see where in my workspace is a field actually being used. If I select it and press ***<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>*** i get all the references to it, but there's a drawback that if in the JavaDoc section someone mentioned that name, i get search results for those too.

So if i have a field called "user" and i want to see where it's being used, i get a ton of search results for every method that mentions "user" as a parameter in the javadoc...

Comment: How about "Ctrl + Alt + H"? Is that any better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using ***<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>*** that will show every line your variable/method occures in current class. Or ***<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>*** for every method using your variable.